# Java, pointer like way to program this

Tags: java

```
boolean d1 = false, d2 = false;

void func(boolean b)
{
    b = !b;
}

void caller()
{
    func(d1);
    System.out.println(d1);//I expect the value of d1 to be true
}
```

How to change the value of `d1` by passing `d1`'s pointer?

Comment: This question appears to lack any research.

Comment: Java is always [pass by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) that might be helpful understanding that

Comment: In java the methods (thanks to @Luiggi Mendoza)parameters are passed by value. When the function "func(param)" is called, an copy of "param" is made, and any changes on "func()" takes effect on copy.

Comment: @ColdHack Java has no functions, it has methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no pointers in Java. Instead, return the value:

```
boolean func(boolean b)
{
    return !b;
}
```

And in `caller`:

```
d1 = func(d1);
System.out.println(d1);
```

This will print `true`.

If you have multiple things to pass into the method, put it in an object. For example, let's say you have a Person class:

```
class Person {

    public String name;
    public String lastName;
}
```

Now let's say you want a method that will change the name of Person:

```
void changeName(Person p) {
    p.name = "Jon";
    p.lastName = "Skeet";
}
```

Since objects are passed by reference, this will work.

Comment: I can do this, but I am looking for a way to deal with many variables instead of only one.

Comment: @Luka pass an object instead.

Comment: wrap all of them in an object

Comment: Then use objects. Put all the variables you want in an object, and pass the object. I'll elaborate on that...

Comment: This won't work on immutable objects. Also, this is covered in the duplicate Q/A.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I wrote this before it was closed, and it's just the general idea.